# debian docker -> reverse proxy with geoip

Tags: docker

I use NPM Nginx Proxy Manager to add TLS to my WordPress and Nextcloud docker containers.

As I use this service only in Germany I want to add geoip (MaxMind) to restrict Port 443 and Port 80 to German WAN Addresses.

As NPM does not have this feature I tried the following:

1. Use NFTables on the docker host debian server => I disabled the iptables rules and created [docker nftables rules](https://gist.github.com/goll/bdd6b43c2023f82d15729e9b0067de60) and added [nftables geoip](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/GeoIP_matching).
   Result: Works but is super slow, the first request from an IP takes approx 15s to resolve
2. I tried to add [luajit-geoip](https://github.com/leafo/luajit-geoip) to the openresty based Nginx Proxy Manager
   but I am not familiar enough with Lua and there is no documentation.

My Question:
**Has anyone a tip for a working reverse proxy docker container with GeoIPthat performs well?**
I try to avoid solutions that are done on the docker host server.